# o que é o asp:Content?

Tags: asp.net, aspx

O que ele é?
O que ele faz?
Porque não consigo colocar um `<body>` dentro dele?
Eu consigo mudar algo nele via CSS?

Tipo de projeto que eu fiz, padrão do vs não deixa a pagina ficar sem essa tag, porém queria alterar meu formulario via CSS e não consigo colocar as tag html dentro dele, tanto a descrita na terceira pergunta quando a `<form>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para entender o funcionamento da tag `<asp:Content...>` é preciso entender os conceitos de *master page* e *content page*.

O `Asp.Net` permite que uma página possa ser segmentada em pequenas partes, sendo uma parte "fixa" que é chamada de *master page*, que pode ser uma estrutura de *layout*.

Imagine que todas ou várias páginas do seu site terão um *layout* parecido, como header e menu no topo e um rodapé ao final. Para evitar ter de "duplicar" esse código em cada página, você cria uma "master page" com esse layout, e cria outras páginas apenas com o conteúdo que vai mudar.

Veja esse exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa página, além do conteúdo de html, vai ter uma estrutura semelhante a essa, e vamos chamá-la de "Master1.master":

```
<%@ Master Language="CS" %>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div><asp:contentplaceholder id="Header" runat="server" /></div>
       <div><asp:contentplaceholder id="PageSpecific" runat="server" /></div>
       <div><asp:contentplaceholder id="Advertisement" runat="server" /></div>
       <div><asp:contentplaceholder id="Recomended" runat="server" /></div>
       <div><asp:contentplaceholder id="Footer" runat="server" /></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Note duas coisas:

- a tag `<%@ Master` no início, indicando que é uma master page
- a tag `<asp:contentplaceholder`, indicando que alguma página vai "implementar" essa parte

Agora vem a segunda parte, a *content page*, que é a página de conteúdo que vai "compor" uma parte da *master page*, e é aqui que entra a tag da sua pergunta, `<asp:Content>`.

Vejamos uma página que vai compor o "header" por exemplo:

```
<%@ Page Language="CS" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Master1.master" Title="Content Page" %>

<asp:Content ID="Header1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Header" Runat="Server">
    <header>Aqui vai o header </header>
</asp:Content>
```

Note aqui duas coisas importantes:

- o atributo `MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Master1.master"`, dizendo que essa página vai compor uma parte da *master page* "Master1.master", aquela criada acima.
- a tag `<asp:Content ID="Header1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Header"`, indicando que o conteúdo dessa página irá compor o "Header" da *master page*.

Ou seja, é uma página parcial, dai a limitação quanto as tags. Como faz parte de uma master, tags como `<html>`, `<head>` e `<body>` não devem existir aqui, mas sim na *master page*, pois ao final ambas serão renderizadas como uma única página, e não podemos ter essas tags duplicadas em um mesmo documento, mas você pode adicionar `css` a ele e modificar o estilo normalmente.

Se quiser saber mais, aqui uma referência da documentação da Microsoft: [ASP.NET Master Pages Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/wtxbf3hh(v=vs.100))